# Creating a modal window in product edit page in Shopware6 and saving data to custom table(repository) from a form within the modal window

Tags: vue.js, plugins, shopware6, administration

I'm a noob to shopware 6 and I have been struggling for a week to add a field to product entity just like admin can add a address in customer overview dynamically.

[Customer address detail page] [Modal popup to save address data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2iw6.png)][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OW4Q.png)]

I have followed this to add a single field in product entity
https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities.html

I have managed to create and save it to single field but I want the fields to be added and contents of it saved dynamically.

I have then switched to add a field within a modal popup in a custom tab in product edit page ( like in but I'm not able to save the field

I have added code as a link
https://ray.so/puiipzV